# Quantization of photon field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, tensor-calculus, quantum-electrodynamics, polarization

I was following Prof David Tong's notes on quantum field theory (Chapter 6, page 134). Consider a physical state $|\Psi\rangle$ in Fock space for N photons. If we consider these photons to have 4 degrees of freedom (as it was assumed at first during the quantization of photon field), we can assume 4N physical states orthogonal to each other will span the space (each photon state acting as a sub-basis). Consider each of these N states is the 4-polarization vector $\epsilon^{\lambda}(\vec{p})$ for $\lambda=0$, $1$, $2$, $3$. If occupation numbers are $n1$, $n2$, $n3$, $n4$ for individual states respectively, where $n1+n2+n3+n4=N$, then $|\Psi\rangle$ can be decomposed into its subspaces as $$|\Psi\rangle= {\epsilon^{0}}^{\otimes n1} \otimes {\epsilon^{1}}^{\otimes n2}\otimes {\epsilon^{2}}^{\otimes n3}\otimes {\epsilon^{3}}^{\otimes n4}$$
David Tong in his notes decomposes $|\Psi\rangle$ as $$|\Psi\rangle=|\Psi_T\rangle \otimes|\Phi\rangle$$ Are these two expressions the same? Can we compose two states into a single subspace such as a combination of subspaces ${\epsilon^{1}}^{\otimes n2} \otimes {\epsilon^{2}}^{\otimes n3}$ will give another subspace $|\Psi_T\rangle$ ? $|\Psi_T\rangle$  stands for transverse photons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but you're right that the subspace of transversely polarized states (aka the physical subspace) is the part of the bigger space which is annihilated by $a_0$ and $a_3$.

Why $a_3$? It is just a convention to have the third polarization vector pointing in the same direction as the 3-momentum $\vec{p}$ of the photon.
Note that the direction of $a_3$ is different for different $\vec{p}$.

The physical / transversely polarized space is a space where each excitation with 3-momentum $\vec{p}$ has a polarization that is orthogonal to it, that is, lies in the span of $\{e_1, e_2\}$.

Comment: Thank you for answering. My doubt is whether we can decompose the state $|\Psi\rangle=|n1,n2,n3,n4\rangle$ as $$|\Psi\rangle=|\Psi_T\rangle|\Phi\rangle$$ where $|\Psi\rangle=a_q^{1\dagger}a_q^{2\dagger}a_q^{3\dagger}a_q^{0\dagger}|0\rangle$ , $|\Psi_T\rangle=a_q^{1\dagger}a_q^{2\dagger}|0\rangle$ and $|\Phi\rangle=a_q^{0\dagger}a_q^{3\dagger}|0\rangle $

Comment: As itzykson zuber in their book of quantum field theory (page 130) stated that "Since condition (3-113) (this is the gupta-blueler condition) is
linear, we can consider basis states obtained by acting on the vacuum with
(smeared) products of creation operators pertaining to the various polarizations.
We therefore factorize these states as $$|\Psi\rangle=|\Psi_T\rangle|\Phi\rangle$$" My doubt is how this state factorization and  basis states obtained by acting on the vacuum with
(smeared) products of creation operators pertaining to the various polarizations related?