# Decomposition of states into subspaces while using Gupta-Bleuler condition

Tags: quantum-field-theory, photons, hilbert-space, quantum-electrodynamics

I am studying quantum field theory using David Tong's notes available at http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html and I am stuck at page 134. I do not understand how to decompose $|\Psi\rangle$ as $$|\Psi\rangle=|\Psi_T\rangle \otimes|\Phi\rangle.$$
Can anyone kindly provide some mathematical description of this argument?

Comment: To maximaze your chances of getting a concise and to-the-point answer, please try to make questions self-contained.

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov please see a similar kind of question which is self-contained. Yet no answer received. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/525733/quantization-of-photon-field